# Using Android.Hardware.SensorManager.RegisterListener with Custom Rate

Tags: mono, xamarin, xamarin.android

According to [Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#registerListener%28android.hardware.SensorEventListener,%20android.hardware.Sensor,%20int%29) and [Xamarin Android](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=M%3aAndroid.Hardware.SensorManager.RegisterListener%28Android.Hardware.ISensorEventListener%2cAndroid.Hardware.Sensor%2cAndroid.Hardware.SensorDelay%29), as of Android 2.3 (API level 9) you can use a custom rate in microseconds for the sensor delay, instead of a SensorDelay enum when registering a listener for a sensor:

> The rate Android.Hardware.SensorEvent are delivered at. This is only a hint to the system. Events may be received faster or slower than the specified rate. Usually events are received faster. The value must be one of SensorDelay.Normal, SensorDelay.Ui, SensorDelay.Game, or SensorDelay.Fastest or, the desired delay between events in microseconds. Specifying the delay in microseconds only works from Android 2.3 (API level 9) onwards. For earlier releases, you must use one of the SENSOR_DELAY_* constants.

I am using Xamarin Android 4.4 and I can not seem to find an overload of the RegisterListener function that accepts an int for the custom rate. I am looking for a Xamarin Android equivalent to Android's `public boolean registerListener (SensorEventListener listener, Sensor sensor, int rateUs)`.

Any clarifications or guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The overload is not provided by Xamarin, so a good alternative is to just make the method call directly via JNI:

```
var sensorManager = SensorManager.FromContext(ctx);
ISensorEventListener listener = ...;
Sensor sensor = sensorManager.GetDefaultSensor(SensorType.Accelerometer);
int samplingPeriodUs = ...;

var method = JNIEnv.GetMethodID(sensorManager.Class.Handle, "registerListener", "(Landroid/hardware/SensorEventListener;Landroid/hardware/Sensor;I)Z");
bool result = JNIEnv.CallBooleanMethod(sensorManager.Handle, method, new JValue(listener.Handle), new JValue(sensor.Handle), new JValue(samplingPeriodUs));
```